# Express the coefficients of the differential equation in terms of linearly independent solutions.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $u_1$ and $u_2$ be linearly independent solutions of the normal second order linear differential equation

$y^{''}+a_1(x)y^{'}+a_0(x)y=0$.

Express the coefficients $a_0(x)$ and $a_1(x)$ in terms of $u_1$ and $u_2$.

The book where i found this problem gives a hint as: ''let $y$ be an arbitrary solution of the equation, and consider the Wronskian of $y, u_1,u_2$''. I attempt to use this hint but i couldn't go further and i haven't any idea to proceed. So, please help me in solving this problem.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Write the differential equation down for both solutions and rotate your point of view by 90° to see the coefficients as variables and the derivatives and function values as constants. Then you have a 2x2 linear system to solve.